# Which has better performance? Add or Copy and Remove in ArrayList?

Tags: android, performance, arraylist

I have SQLite database with roughtly thousands of records on my android device, and I need to quickly build from them an ArrayList to view some of records. So which one is faster?

```
            List<Items> values = database.getAllItems();
            List<Items> valuesBuffer = new ArrayList<Items>();
            for (Items item : values) {
                if ((item.getItemToScan() == 1) && 
                                 (item.getItemScanned() != item.getItemAmount()))
                {
                    valuesBuffer.add(item);
                }
            }
```

Or

```
            List<Items> values = database.getAllItems();
            List<Items> valuesBuffer = new ArrayList<Items>(values);
            for (Items item : values) {
                if ((item.getItemToScan() != 1) || 
                                 (item.getItemScanned() == item.getItemAmount()))
                {
                    valuesBuffer.remove(item);
                }
            }
```

Also probably checking or (||) logic takes on average more time...

Comment: measure it. http://developer.android.com/reference/android/util/TimingLogger.html

Comment: what do you need ArrayList for?

Comment: as a side note, filtering in database would probably be more efficient.

Comment: List of objects from database. In my case ~3500 objects with 12 fields in each object containing texts, longs and rarely bytes.

Comment: That's good point, I could implement something like getAllToScanItems(). I'll probably do it now :D

Comment: About measuring, can I measure on emulator or should I only do it on real device? At the moment I have only emulator, and data reading is done in AsyncTask, that is why I fear that measures will differ a lot from measure to measure and won't be propper...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first one.

Because `remove` is an `o(n)` operation anyway (in this case because a/ you need to find the index to the item and b/ you need to shift all items one row down), the overall complexity is `o(n^2)`.

The complexity of the first is amortized `o(n)`, and could be plain `o(n)` by initializing the arraylist with a sufficient size : `new ArrayList<Items>(values.size());`

### edit

all that really depends on how many items are filtered out. If that number is a known to be bounded to a constant, the complexity becomes `o(n)` in both cases. If it is unknown, the answer above stands.

Answer (score 1):

I do not think there is clear answer to this one. But if you have some knowledge about the values you can do some optimizations.

If you are expecting the majority of elements to be removed(or added in the first case) than the better solution is to use method one because you will not do many removes. If if you are expecting to remove just a few elements it's better to use the second method because copying the array is cheaper than adding elements one by one.

Comment: edit from previous comment : it probably depends on how many items you have to remove

Comment: Yes, for this particular implementation you are right. I was answering on the more generic question which of the two methods is faster. After all you can implement the removal with iterator and than the cost of each remove will be O(1).

Comment: in an arraylist, regardless of using an iterator, you still have to move all the items after the item you remove one notch down, which is always `o(n)`. Another structure (a linkedlist for instance) could be more appropriate.

Comment: Since I expect most of the time to remove a lot (add not that much) elements it looks it's better to use copy/add version. Thank you for help :)